# Where did these songs appear in Black Rock Shooter?

Tags: music, black-rock-shooter

I imported soundtracks for the Black Rock Shooter anime series (not OVA). As per my normal procedure, after getting them, I then searched for torrents of the same soundtracks so I could get ripped .mp3 versions (or FLAC which I could then convert to .mp3) which had the metadata and cover scans for when I put it on my iPod/iPhone (saves up on time having to edit 7589+ songs).

In the process, I found out that I didn't have one of the soundtracks in the torrent. It consisted of 3 tracks. (Note: these are how the track title meta data had them named)

1. Re:Make
2. NO SCARED
3. Rock,Scissors,Paper

All 3 had the Artist Meta Tag as ONE OK ROCK and the Album Title as AZCS-2013 (I think it's a catalog number). Below is the corresponding cover scan.

[image]

Though I didn't buy the soundtrack, I decided to listen to it to see if I had missed a soundtrack. It was good music, but I don't remember any of it. I know it's definitely not the Opening as that's the Hitsune Miku Black Rock Shooter song.

I would like to buy it, but first I want to know where in Black Rock Shooter these songs came from? (Quite possibly only 1 was used). If they happen to come from a different Black Rock Shooter media, I would like to know what it is so I can get it and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

No Scared is the opening to Black Rock Shooter: The Game (on PSP).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnATga1UdHg

Comment: To add, "Re;Make" and "Rock, Scissors, Paper" were not used in any BRS things as far as I know - they're just other songs on the same album.